# How can I tell if I'm on a taxonomy page in preprocess_page?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

If I'm on a node, inside preprocess_page(&$variables), I can check

`if (isset($variables['node']) && $variables['node']->bundle() == 'my-type')`

to see if I'm on a node, and a node of a certain type.

Then I can get field information with

```
$variables['node']->field_icon->entity->getFileUri()
```

How can I do the same thing for a taxonomy term page to know that I'm on a taxonomy term page and get the field values?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately I don't think there is anything that the hook gives you directly that you can use in this instance. However you can always check the route name to determine if you are on a taxonomy term page.

```
// Will be "true" if you are currently on a taxonomy term page.
if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'entity.taxonomy_term.canonical') {

  // Since this is a taxonomy term page, you may wish to get the term ID.
  $term_id = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('taxonomy_term');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To check term data in theme_preprocess_page for drupal 7. you can use below code.

```
if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(1) == 'term') {
if (isset($variables['page']['content']['system_main']['term_heading']['term']['#term'])) {
  $term_data = $variables['page']['content']['system_main']['term_heading']['term']['#term'];
}
```

}

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is two ways to get the term in `preprocess_page`.

1. Get the tid from parameter and then load the term.
2. Get the Term directly from ParameterBag.
   Her is code snippet

```
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function myModule_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  // Get the tid.
  $tid = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('taxonomy_term');
  // Load the term.
  $term = Term::load($tid);

   // Get possible params.
   /** @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag $possible_parameters */
   $possible_parameters = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameters();
    // Get term
    $term = $possible_parameters->get('taxonomy_term');
}
```